# Spring MVC - How to display blank textbox when integer value is zero

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Im using spring, hibernate, java, and jsp. My problem is that when the integer value is zero it displays `0` in my textbox. I want to display only empty string but Idk how to do it. Please help.

In my jsp:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="division">
...
...
    <form:input path="number"/>
</form:form>
```

In my domain:

```
/**
 * Get the number of the division.
 * @return The number.
 */
@Column(name = "NUMBER")
public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

/**
 * Set the number of the division.
 * @param number The division number.
 */
public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}
```

Comment: can you show us your jsp code and relevant servlet code?It is not possible answer these type of questions without checking the code.

Comment: make your property of `Integer` type not `int`. when you try to put a primitive `int` value it will autobox/unbox it and you will have empty when property has no value until you explicitly make it 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use `spring:bind` for that.

Also, you will have to use *JSTL*. Import it with:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="core" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

In order to get the value for `number`:

```
<spring:bind path="number">
```

The result of the `spring:bind` is returned in a variable called `status`, in its `value` field. Check if it is 0 and print nothing, else print the number:

```
<core:if test="${status.value != 0}">
    ${status.value}    
</core:if>
```

For more information, take a look at the [spring:bind documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/tag/BindTag.html).